# Making a 3 x 8 grid with tetrominoes

Tags: tiling, polyomino

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a 3x8 grid using 6 [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino): 2 Is, 2 Ls, a Z skew, and a square tetromino. I believe it may be impossible but would like to know why.

Comment: Even if the L tetronimoes are both right Ls and not a left and right L? I can't see how without flipping the tetronimoes

Comment: Can you please give an explicit definition of the tiles, or if those are standard, a link to a description?

Comment: @Plop - They are standard names, I've added a link to the wikipedia page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is

> possible:

> ```
>     1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3
>     4 1 1 5 5 5 3 3
>     4 4 4 5 6 6 6 6
> ```

> Without flipping an "L":

> ```
>     1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
>     4 4 5 5 5 2 2 3
>     4 4 5 6 6 6 6 3
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to make that one myself I think my L shapes are orientated differently but using your answer I have made the following

Comment: Problem I have is my L tetronimoes are both of the form of 5 and not 4 so I can't create a grid

Comment: @JohnWilliams That's possible, too, see updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic. Is this unique or is there another that could be formed?

Answer (score 5):

All the ways it can be tiled. Five ways, if you want to search by hand...
Two ways use a mirrored pair of Ls. I have a program that does this sort of thing, started writing it when the IBM PC was released so it's out of control now in terms of code length/maintainability.

> [image]

Comment: You should note that only one of those uses two Ls and a Z. The flipped versions of these are J and S.

Comment: @DanielMathias Since OP referred to 'tetrominoes' not 'one-sided tetrominoes', I take 'L' to mean 'L or it's mirror'. This is the generally accepted terminology. Of course I accept that OP might have intended it the way you said too...

Comment: OP's comments indicate one-sided tetrominoes. That's why I suggested the note.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible; I wrote a small C++ program to find a solution: https://godbolt.org/z/rdjb7n66s

Sample solution:

> ```
>  L I I I I L O O
>  L Z Z L L L O O
>  L L Z Z I I I I
> ```